# Importing Text File as Zoo in R

Tags: r, date, zoo

I am trying to import a text file with data that looks like:

```
Jan 1998     4.36
Feb 1998     4.34
Mar 1998     4.35
Apr 1998     4.37
May 1998     4.45
Jun 1998     4.54
Jul 1998     4.52
Aug 1998     4.68
Sep 1998     4.82
Oct 1998     4.72
Nov 1998     4.80
...
```

as a zoo in R. I have tried importing it directly as a zoo:

```
install.packages("zoo")
library("zoo")    
FMAGX_prices <- read.csv.zoo("filepath.../FMAGX_prices.csv", format = "%m/%Y")
```

and importing it as a data frame and then converting it to a zoo. The reason I create the dates vector re-assign it to the front of the data frame is that by default, I get a 3 column data frame, one with the month abbreviation, one with the year, and one with the price:

```
install.packages("zoo")
library("zoo")     
FMAGX_prices <-read.table("filepath.../FMAGX_prices.txt")
dates <- paste(FMAGX_prices$V1, FMAGX_prices$V2, sep = " ")
FMAGX_prices$V3 <- as.numeric(as.character(FMAGX_prices$V3))
FMAGX_prices$dates <- dates
FMAGX_prices <- subset(FMAGX_prices, select= c(dates, V3))
FMAGX_prices <- read.zoo(FMAGX_prices, "%b %Y")
```

neither method works. I always get the below error:

```
Error in read.zoo(FMAGX_prices, format = "%b %Y") : 
  index has 144 bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11...
```

My assumption is that there is something wrong with my date format, but I am not sure what it would be.

I've tried various combinations of arguments in the read statements, I've added headers, I've reformatted the data as a CSV, changed the dates to 01/1998, 02/1998, etc (and the corresponding arguments), but I always get that same error

Comment: CSV stands for *comma separated values*. I don't see any commas in your data. Maybe try `read.zoo` with `sep = "\t"` for tab separation? (Depending on what the separator in your raw data is.)

Comment: `read.zoo(text = "Jan 1998     4.36\nFeb 1998     4.34", index = 1:2, FUN = paste, FUN2 = as.yearmon)`

Comment: See also the excellent vignette [Reading Data in zoo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-read.pdf) with loads of examples.

Comment: @Gregor: good point. Careless copy/pasting from a different part of my script, I had converted it to a csv to try to get it to work. Unfortunately, that didn't work, but thanks!

Comment: @Henrik: thanks. this worked. For anyone who happens to see this after the fact, I used read_file from the readr package to read the file itself into a string so I didn't have to copy/paste all of my data into read.zoo statement (which did also work)

Comment: @Henrik: I saw that pdf, but thank you. I think I get the index argument (my dates are in the first two columns?), but what is FUN (in plain English)? What is the difference between FUN2 and trying to specify the date format using format = "%b %Y"

Comment: Well, my use of `text` was just for this small example ;) Normally you would use `file = `, like you did in your question.